# Is it possible to create an array with angle changed like this?

Tags: modifiers

I need to create an array to make leaves for the palm tree. I tried to use it with empty object, but it always make the "circular" shape, wherever I set the position and origin of empty and object. The result I'd like to achive is shown below. This way I could have contron on the number and the size of the leaves.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to do it with the array modifier but,
you can start with one, them <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and move it over a bit.
Then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the last step a couple times.
Then turn on proportional editing and rotate the last one.
Scroll the mouse wheel to increase the effected range and you can change the [falloff type](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html#options) of the proportional editing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some attempts that can help : 
[image: https://gyazo.com/4f5ad411040cb8b4565f2e64778edb76]

- Upper left : an array and a curve modifier
- Lower left : the same but using a vertex group on the curve modifier
- Upper right : an array and a mesh deform modifier
- Lower right : the same but again using a vertex group on the mesh deform

Comment: please link images directly into the answer. see: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Answer (score 1):

Create the base object, a curve and an empty.

On your base object add an array modifier and set the object offset to use the empty.

Add a Curve modifier and set the curve as your control object.

By changing the size, rotation and placement of the empty along with the shape of the curve you should be able to do what you want.

[image]